# Include github packages as imports in DESCRIPTION

Tags: r, package, devtools

I'm using devtools and I have some packages on github.  I would like to create dependencies between them, so when I run `install_github(...)` the other github packages that are in the DESCRIPTION file listed as Imports will also be installed.  Can I do this or is there another thing people do?

Currently if I add a package to Imports that isnt available on CRAN I simply get a message "Skipping ... packages not available: xxx" when I run `install_github`.

Comment: (I don't know.) So you want `install_github` to check the dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file and install them? According to the help page a "dependencies" argument would get passed to `devtools::install`. I think you should include your full code that generates the warning or error.

Comment: As I said, I don't know the answer, but the questions that occurred to me was whether you were setting dependencies=TRUE in the call and had the 'github'-URL in your "repos" value for `options()`.

Comment: You **can do this** if you use packages, stored for examples in a [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) repository---which you can have on GitHub for free.

Comment: It has been used by a lot of people now. You can even have CRAN packages refer back for Suggests: via Addtional_Repositories: pointing to such a drat repo.

Comment: http://http://eddelbuettel.github.io/drat/  `<g>`

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thank you for the Suggests and Additonal_repositories tidbit. This would make a useful Q/A on its own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to get R's package loaders to install from github sounds like a [rabbit hole](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rabbit+Hole).

Instead, use something like this in your [package's](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html) `.onload()` method.

```
# install these from github, not CRAN:
pkglist <- list(
    c(name='ggplus',url='guiastrennec/ggplus'),
    c(name='DT',url='rstudio/DT'))

for(pkg in pkglist)
    if(!suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(pkg['name'],
        quietly=TRUE,character.only=TRUE)))){
        devtools::install_github(pkg['url'])
        suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(pkg['name'],character.only=TRUE))
    }
```

Comment: You are reinventing package management.  This may end in tears.

Comment: @Dirk, I'll agree that the first block is re-inventing package management, but the latter allows flexibility to load local repositories `c:\myPackage`  which is useful for private packages that are not on a service like Github.  PS. `drat` looks cool.  I'll definitely be checking that one out.

Answer (score 21):

You can add a github dependency in the DESCRIPTION file with `Remotes:` like this:

```
Imports:
    mypackage
Remotes:
    mygithub/mypackage
```

See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html for how to add non-github dependencies.

Comment: will this install all dependencies of `mypackage`?